# Hybris login user programmatically

Tags: sap-commerce-cloud

Given a user ID and his password, how can I perform a login programatically in Hybris? I'm trying to use `de.hybris.platform.acceleratorstorefrontcommons.security.AutoLoginStrategy#login` but I't doesn't work.

I have created an method used to activate an registered account which receives via GET params the user id and password and then I try to log using autologinstrategy.

Any hint?

Comment: Can you explain why 'it doesn't work'? We've used AutoLoginStrategy and it works just fine. So in your URL it will looks like `/accounts/activate?username=xxx&password=yyyy` ?

Comment: It just doesn't do anything nor throwing any exception